# workflow 4 long running bookmark

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4

Let's say i have a workflow that has been executer on a WCF service, and its waiting for the user input for some value.

What is the best approach to implement this scenario?

I've read that the concept of bookmark can be use for long-running workflow. But is the bookmark being persisted somewhere? Since the external input can take a very long time, what if the wcf service shut down, can the Workflow be resumed?

What are other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you hosting your workflow as a workflow serivce? If so a WCF operation is a wrapper for a bookmark. While waiting for a bookmark to resume your workflow can be persisted to SQL Server using the instance store. That way it doesn't eat up memory and you can restart IIS or the complete machine.

If you are self hosting using the WorklfowApplication you can do the same with the instance store except you need to more work around resuming and managing workflow instances.

Comment: Thanks, my scenario is the second one, do you have any articles, resources about this?

Comment: Not of the top of my head. However I normally advise people to go the workflow services route for long running workflows. And in your case that would be easy as you already have a WCF service you can add a workflow service and use a local WCF connection to talk to the service. It might sound more complicated than just creating a WorkflowApplication but it will save you a lot of work/code managing individual workflow instances.